# What does a hexadecapole look like?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, multipole-expansion

Two dipoles can form a quadrupole, two quadropoles an octopole. The textbook by Griffith then says ' and so on'. So how would a hexadecapole really look like? My impression was that the construction seems to rely on going to higher and higger dimensions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hexadecapole potential using point particles?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65651/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to visualise the various multipoles is through [their connection with the spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_spherical_harmonics). These are probably best known as the functions that give the shape of the atomic orbitals in the hydrogen atom.

[image: Spherical Harmonics]

The $p$ orbitals correspond to a dipole, the $d$ orbitals to  quadrupole and the $f$ orbitals to an octapole, that is a charge distribution of this shape creates a dipole/quadrupole/octapole. So a charge distribution creating a hexadecapole [would look like the $g$ orbitals](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=g%20orbital).

**Later:**

I've just spotted [Hexadecapole potential using point particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65651/hexadecapole-potential-using-point-particles), which gives the same answer I've given so I suppose this question is a duplicate.